# iptablesでリモートホストからのssh接続を許可する方法

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

以前、多用途サーバーを建てる際にお世話になった者です。`iptables`のことで少しお伺いしたいことがあり、このトピックを建てさせていただきました。

#### 本題

多機能サーバーを構築してルーターに登録し、DDNSによりリモートホストを取得したまではいいのですが、よりセキュリティを強固にすべく齧ったばかりの`iptables`でルールをこちらの[サイト](https://knowledge.sakura.ad.jp/4048/)を参考に設定しました。なおリモートホストは[こちら](https://ddns.kuku.lu/)で取得しました。しかし、これだとリモートホストからの`ssh`ログインができなくなることに気づきました(パブリックキーの権限がない)。そこで、今のところはこの設定をできるだけ維持、改良しつつ、リモートホストからのログインが可能な設定へ変更することを試みましたが、現在の私が持っているiptabelesの知識だけでは到底及ばない問題であることに気づき慌ててトピックを建てさせていただきました。

#### サーバー側のiptablesの設定ファイルの詳細

```
*filter

:INPUT    DROP    [0:0]
:FORWARD  DROP    [0:0]
:OUTPUT   ACCEPT  [0:0]

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name t_icmp --hashlimit 1/m --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-htable-expire 120000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --syn --state NEW --dport 2222 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name t_sshd --hashlimit 1/m --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-htable-expire 120000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

この設定にどのような手を加えるとリモートホストからのログインが可能になるのでしょうか？
先生方、どうかご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: パッと見は `2222` で許可しているように見えますが、「sshログインができなくなることに気づいた」根拠はなんですか？ / 接続の際はポート番号 `2222` を指定する必要があるのとは別に、何かエラー等が表示されているなら、それらの情報も質問文に含めるようにしてください。

Comment: すみません、コマンドラインでユーザー名を追加するのを忘れていました。ご足労をおかけして本当に申し訳ありません。何分、サーバーを建てる経験は初めてなもので、ついパニックになってしまいました。これからは葉隠の心を忘れず。冷静に物事を処理していきます